# Como actualizar valores de variables en python con condicional

Tags: python-3.x

tengo este código.

```
variable_x = 1
variable_y = 2
resx = round(0.2-(0.4*variable_y), 4)
resy = 0.25*resx
Ecu1 = 5*resx + 2*resy
Ecu2 = resx - 4*resy

data = [[variable_x,variable_y,resx,resy,Ecu1,Ecu2]]

def algoritmo(resx,resy):
    resx = round(0.2-(0.4*variable_y), 4)
    resy = 0.25*resx
    Ecu1 = round(5*resx + 2*resy, 4)
    Ecu2 = resx - 4*resy
    data.append([variable_x,variable_y,resx,resy,Ecu1,Ecu2])

if Ecu1 != 1.0:
    variable_x = resx
    variable_y = resy
    algoritmo(resx,resy)

print(data)
```

La salida es esta

`[[1, 2, -0.6, -0.15, -3.3, 0.0], [-0.6, -0.15, 0.26, 0.065, 1.43, 0.0]]`

El punto es que quiero que se añadan los valores a **data** hasta que **Ecu1 = 1**, ya lo hice en excel y solo necesito 10 iteraciones para que Ecu1 vaya disminuyendo su valor hasta llegar a 1, pero no se como hacerlo. Ya que quiero alguna forma para que se hagan iteraciones y se agregen los valores a la lista hasta que **Ecu1 == 1**
Es un método iterativo que necesito para una tarea pero si el **if** lo mando a llamar mas veces por ejemplo con un for, esto es lo que pasa.

`[[1, 2, -0.6, -0.15, -3.3, 0.0], [-0.6, -0.15, 0.26, 0.065, 1.43, 0.0], [-0.6, -0.15, 0.26, 0.065, 1.43, 0.0], [-0.6, -0.15, 0.26, 0.065, 1.43, 0.0], [-0.6, -0.15, 0.26, 0.065, 1.43, 0.0]]`

Después de la segunda iteracion, los valores de **variable_x** y **variable_y** ya no cambian. Es por eso que salen los mismos resultados.

En pocas palabras necesito ayuda:

1. Algún condicional para que se agregen valores a la lista hasta que **Ecu1 == 1**
2. Para que los valores **variable_x** y **variable_y** se actualicen.

De antemano, muchas gracias, es lo único que me falta de mi programa :(

Comment: Sin haber entrado a mirar en detalle tu código, sospecho que puede tratarse de un error de redondeo. Es posible que  `Ecu1` nunca llegue a ser exactamente igual a 1, sino a 0.999999 por ejemplo. Estas cosas pasan al trabajar con números de punto flotante. Te recomiendo cambiar la condición por `if abs(Ecu1-1.0) < 0.00001` por ejemplo, o la cantidad que consideres apropiada a tu caso

Comment: El valor de `Ecu1`  es -3.3 y nunca cambia. Revisa el algoritmo.

Comment: Nunca preguntes por igualdad con punto flotante; pregunta por la diferencia absoluta `abs(Ecu1 - 1.0)`, que te da el error respecto al resultado deseado. Cuando está diferencia sea menor al límite, terminas.

Comment: La función recibe dos parámetros que no ocupa; los modifica de inmediato a partir de variables globales.